# How to show a progress bar in android while waiting to recieve an sms for 5 mintues?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-dialog

**My Question**

How to show a progress bar in android while waiting to receive an SMS?

The dialog should fulfill the following conditions

- The dialog should be dismissed in maximum for 5 minutes.
- The dialog should be dismissed if SMS is received before 5 minutes.

**What I tried**

```
public class GetSMS extends Activity {
   ...
   ...
   private boolean progressDialogFlag;
   private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
   ...
   ...
   new SMSReceiver().execute();
}

public class SMSReceiver extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // start a progressdialog box
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialogFlag = true;
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Waiting to Receive SMS...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        if (progressDialogFlag == true) {
            progressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }
        if (progress[0] == 100 || progressDialogFlag == false) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        int interval = 2;
        int totalDuration = 5 * 60 * 1000; // 5 min
        int sleepPeriod = (totalDuration / 100) * interval;
        for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i += 2) {
            publishProgress(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepPeriod);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

smsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              progressdialog = false;
   }
}
```

**What are my doubts**

- I think the use of `progressDialogFlag` to dismiss the `progressDialog` when an Sms is received before 5 min is causing the problem.
- The use of variable `progressDialogFlag` in UI and worker thread is causing some kind of race condition.

Thanks for help.

Comment: But my suggestion is, if you show a progress bar for five minutes, definitely the user is gonna get frustrated. How are you going to manage it?

Comment: @AndroSelva That is the maximum limit, dialog will be dismissed as soon as SMS is received. Now if there is no other option this has to be it.

Answer (score 0):

can try some thing like below when you start the progressDialog

```
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
               if(null!=progressDialog && progressDialog.isShowing()){
                  // try{
                   progressDialog.dismiss();
               }

            }
        }, 5*60*1000);
```

but need some more checks......

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
private ProgressDialog p;

private void sendSMS(){
     p = new ProgressDialog(Context);
     registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, SMSINTENT);
}

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        p.dismiss();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(this);

    }
};
```

Don't know if it is the best solution, but it works!